# How to properly clear another field on checkbox click in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a list of checkboxes and one of them is "Other" and what I want is that if "Other" is selected, then a textbox is enabled. If "Other" is not checked, then the textbox must be disabled and its content must be cleared.

Now, the problem is that when I click on the "Other" checkbox, the checkmark doesn't show up or disappear UNTIL I trigger another binding event. I must have on the way of Knockout by adding the click event handler to the "Other" checkbox.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2qdu9tuo/)

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' value='apple' data-bind='checked: selectedFoods' />apple
<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='banana' data-bind='checked: selectedFoods' />banana
<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='other' data-bind='checked: selectedFoods, event: {click: otherClicked}' />other
<input type='text' data-bind="text: otherFoods, attr:{disabled: selectedFoods.indexOf('other') < 0}" />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var BaseVM = function () {
        var that = {};
        return that;
    };

    var TestVM = function () {
        var that = BaseVM();

        that.selectedFoods = ko.observableArray(['apple', 'banana']);
        that.otherFoods = ko.observable(null);

        that.otherClicked = function () {
            if (that.selectedFoods.indexOf('other') < 0) {
                that.otherFoods = '';
            }
        };

        return that;
    };

    var vm = TestVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
that.otherFoods = '';
```

is wrong. You need to assign the value as an observable, since that's what it is:

```
that.otherFoods('');
```

Also, you need to evaluate your array when checking the values:

```
that.selectedFoods.indexOf('other') < 0
```

should be

```
that.selectedFoods().indexOf('other') < 0
```

Edit: and your click handler was set up wrong, see this updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2qdu9tuo/9/

You need to return true in the click handler to let the checkbox still behave like a checkbox. Also, you're using the text binding instead of the value binding on the textbox.

Comment: good catch! also, I need to change the binding for the textbox to `value` from `text`. http://jsfiddle.net/2qdu9tuo/8/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to `return true` from your `click` handler, otherwise the native event would not propagate and the checkbox state will not change.

Also, when resetting the `otherFoods` observable, you need to invoke the observable, not override it:

```
that.otherClicked = function () {
    if (that.selectedFoods.indexOf('other') < 0)
        that.otherFoods('');

    return true;
};
```

Another problem is that you're using the `text` binding handler, for your `otherFoods` input, instead of the `value` handler:

```
<input type='text' data-bind="value: otherFoods, attr:{disabled: selectedFoods.indexOf('other') < 0}" />
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qdu9tuo/7/)